# Sending additional parameters to callback uri in socialite package for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to use Socialite package for laravel and I would like to know how to pass additional parameters to callback url. It seems that OAuth allows additional params, but I haven't found any solution for laravel on how to pass them. Currently my methods look like this

```
    public function login($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::with($provider)->redirect();
    }


   public function callback(SocialAccountService $service, $provider)
    {
        $driver   = Socialite::driver($provider);
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser($driver, $provider);
        $this->auth()->login($user, true);
        return redirect()->intended('/');

    }
```

Suppose I want to get `$user_role` variable in my callback method. How do I pass it there?

Comment: Find the answer here: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/373#issue-457941924

Answer (score 10):

You need to use **state** param if you want to pass some data.

Example for your provider

```
$provider = 'google';
return Socialite::with(['state' => $provider])->redirect();
```

Your callback function:

```
$provider = request()->input('state');
$driver = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless();
```

[gist example](https://gist.github.com/mikicaivosevic/585cb051e969003fbaf47e47b3995750)

Comment: Why does the [documentation say](https://github.com/laravel/socialite):

"When using the `with` method, be careful not to pass any reserved keywords such as `state` or `response_type`."

Comment: The link is dead :\

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/373#issuecomment-703706139

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite#optional-parameters) didn't work for me, so i ended up by using session to pass variables from **redirect** method to the **callback** method. it's not the best way to do it, but it does the trick.

#### Simplified example

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Socialite;

class FacebookController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirect($my_variable)
    {
        session(['my_variable' => $my_variable]);

        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $facebookAccount = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

            $my_variable = session('my_variable');

            // your logic...

            return redirect()->route('route.name');


        } catch (Exception $e) {


            return redirect()->route('auth.facebook');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. the session is not set, I'm using file driver for the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can update on the fly callback URL as like:

```
public function redirectToProvider($providerName)
{
    config([
        "services.$providerName.redirect" => config("services.$providerName.redirect").'?queryString=test'
    ]);

    try {
        return Socialite::driver($providerName)->redirect();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return redirect('login');

    }

}
```

It return **queryString** (request->all()) in callback URL function.

Comment: It does not work. I tested it for google. Following error is displayed by google:

The redirect URI in the request "http://url", does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.