# How to keep a session or cookie alive after visiting and leaving a page?

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

I am trying to build a referral system using the OAuth system, am working with the Laravel framework. So when a user visit the registration page with a referral link it create a cookie and a session. For to register all that is provided is the social button, so whenever the user clicks on the register with Google or Facebook.

Once the user comes back to the site the session and cookie disappear. Why is that? Below are the files I think may be helpful.

Where I created the session and cookie base on the ref

```
if ($request->has('ref')){
            $referral = ReferralLink::whereCode($request->get('ref'))->first();
            $response->cookie('ref', $referral->user_id, $referral->program->lifetime_minutes);
            $_SESSION['ref'] = $referral->user_id;
            request()->session()->put('ref', $referral->user_id);
        }
```

Where I retrieve the session and cookie base on the ref

```
   $session = request()->session()->get('ref');
        dd(request());
        $referral = \App\User\ReferralLink::where('user_id', $event->referralId)->orWhere('user_id', $session)->first();
        // dd($event->user, $event->referralId, $referral);
            if (!is_null($referral)){
                $provider = $referral->user;
                \App\User\ReferralRelationship::create([
                    'referral_link_id' => $referral->id, 
                    'user_id' => $event->user->id,
                    'referree_user_id' =>  $provider->id,
                    'reward'    => 'no',
                    ]);
        }
```

Comment: Delete the `$_SESSION['ref'] = $referral->user_id;` line, maybe it's somehow interfering plus it's unnecessary.

Comment: I know and it did not work

#session: Store {#272 ▼
    #id: "4XpHZOZ07lklnyEaqqRVQdjezw0j4hoM16NBd9fm"
    #name: "laravel_session"
    #attributes: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "tw9LDK72RasBuEvkyp1fhI9BuYmcRFi6fGnu51lO"
      "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
      "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    #handler: FileSessionHandler {#273 ▶}
    #started: true
  }

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use the `state` parameter of the OAuth2 protocol to pass additional parameters. Then, when the user click on any "loggin", and you receive the OAuth2 response, you will get your state back.

The idea would be:

1. Session is on, user have some sessions data
2. We encoded the session id and we ship it on the OAuth request
3. The session will be lost when the user finishes to authenticate him/herself
4. OAuth2 response arrives, session id too
5. Session id is extracted from response, decoded, and we restore the session back

First, get the Session id and encode it:

```
use Session;

// ...

$session_id = Session::getid();
$session_id = base64_encode($session_id);
```

I did not see your OAuth2 request, so we take a dummy example to show how to ship the state (= the encoded session id):

```
$request = "https://authorization-server.com/auth?response_type=code&
  client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=photos&state=$session_id";
```

(the best is to use at least `http_build_query()` or better GuzzleHttp)

Then, the user is authenticated and we get our response back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"photos",
  "state":"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
}
```

And then we will decode it to get back our session id:

```
$response = /* ... */

$state = $response['state'];

$session_id = base64_decode($state);
```

And finally, restore your session:

```
Session::setId($session_id);
Session::start();
```

Comment: am having issue understanding how to input the session state into the request. my request to Oauth is just 127.0.0.1:8000/login/google and am just using laravel socialite so I don't know how to access the OAuth request

Comment: hello @Anwar nairi Please answer

Comment: Hi @AdajOEL sorry I never used Laravel Socialite but you might find this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243813/3753055. Let me know if it helped.